# Why does JSON.parse() miss some objects in this case?

Tags: javascript, json

I have this JSON in a string:

```
{"variables": [{"name": "variable1", "type": "Integer", "id": 0, "asInput": [], "asOutput": [], "onSet": []}], "scripts": [], "action": "updateConfiguration"}
```

Here is a part of a JavaScript script:

```
console.log(myString)
var myObject = JSON.parse(myString)
console.log(myObject)
```

I see the JSON above for the `console.log(myString)`, but this is what I see for the `console.log(myObject)` part:

```
{
    "variables": [
        {}
    ],
    "scripts": [],
    "action": "updateConfiguration"
}
```

The JSON is valid as per JSONlint.

Why is the object inside the `variables` array empty?

(BTW, the same issue arises with the elements of `scripts` if it has any.)

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/8qdyavp3/), `variables` has variables in it.

Comment: Just now i have checked in json editor your json data was not valid json format

Comment: @KrishnaJonnalagadda - The question is a bit unclear, the block with the JSON is the output of the code above. Only the *first* line of that block is the actual JSON (which is valid).

Comment: See the linked question's answers. The explanation for this is probably that the JSON parses just fine, complete with entries in `variables`, `scripts`, etc., but then *after* the `console.log` but *before* you expand that entry in the console, code removes the contents of `variables` and `scripts` (or overwrites those properties entirely). If you replace `console.log(myObject);` with `console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject));`, the full contents at that point in time will be shown.